# Efficient way to get the list with highest size

Tags: list, scala, scala-collections

I have a scala List containing a string and a list of integers. I wanted to filter only those that have largest size of the list of integers. The usual way to sort from highest and lowest,then taking n strings has one drawback.

```
var qq = List[(String,List[Int])]()
```

Say for example a List of length 10,there are 6 list that are of sizes 65 and rest 5 are sizes less than 65. Now i need to retrieve all the 6 list from the vector.

Approaches: Traditional way would be to sort the list,get the size of the highest list and add filter condition with that size.

```
var max = qq.sortWith(_._2.size>_._2.size).head._2.size //get maximum size
var filList = qq.filter(p=>p._2.size>=max) //filter them
```

My question is is there any other fast and efficient way to do this in scala? As i would do this process around 10,000-20,000 times with greater list size.

Comment: Can you switch inner Lists to collection with O(1) length retrieval? Vector, for example.

Answer (score 3):

For performance, you should not sort the whole list if you just want the max.

Secondly, it can be very easy to multi-thread code in Scala:

```
  val data = List(("a", List(1, 2, 3)), ("b", List(4, 5)), ("c", List(45, 3, 2)))
  val maxListSize = data.par.map(_._2.size).max
  val largestLists = data.par.filter(_._2.size == maxListSize)
  println(largestLists)
```

It becomes multi-threaded just by adding `.par` (parallel collection).  Note that unless you have very large lists, you might want to remove those `.par` since they will likely slow things down.  For large lists, the parallelization will give a speed up factor which is the number of cores on your machine.

Comment: Well, it will give a speed-up that is not greater than the number of cores available. Or, as advertising types say "Up to blah-blah-blah!" (which includes zero…).

Comment: I don't know if read my whole post, but I do mention that for small lists, it might actually slow things down.  If the list is very large, it will offer a speed up factor that is asymptotically close to the number of cores.  Why the sarcasm about multi-threaded code?

Comment: The sarcasm was only directed at advertiser-speak, but your statement was not accurate in the answer ("is the number of cores…"), though in the comment where you say "asymptotically close," you're much more accurate.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest

```
val sorted = qq.sortBy(_._2.size)
val thresh = sorted.head._2.size  // assume qq is non-empty
val retain = sorted.takeWhile(_._2.size == thresh)
```

The performance in any case is bound by the sorting procedure (certainly worse than O(N)).

---

A different approach would be to build up your result without sorting at all. Just track the best results and replace them when you detect a list that has greater size.

Like this:

```
type A = (String,List[Int])

((0, List.empty[A]) /: qq) { case (prev @ (bestLen, res), entry @ (_, list)) =>
  val eLen = list.size
  if      (eLen <  bestLen) prev
  else if (eLen == bestLen) (bestLen, entry :: res)
  else                      (eLen, entry :: Nil)
}
```

The performance will be O(N), as good as it gets.

Comment: @toto2 - right, parallelisation notwithstanding. But if we assume that C = number of cores is a constant, this is still O(N) :)

Comment: True.  Big-O notation does not care about constants.   :-<